# How do I get an instagram access token?

Tags: instagram, bots, instagram-api

I'm looking to build [this app](https://github.com/gulzar1996/auto-like-my-gf-insta-pic). I'm having trouble understanding how to get this set-up. I used terminal to download from git to my mac, created a sandbox in instagram- but I don't understand how to get the instagram access token.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: This is not really on topic for SO, as this is not really about coding. A web search is likely to find what you need.

Comment: John is probably posting here because https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/ directed him to do so. That advice makes sense if you're further along and, for example, cannot make a specific API call work how you want it. @John Robert: for now, since you're just setting up, it's harder to help you. If you're following specific instructions from Instagram and they don't work, the same page has a way to report issues. Otherwise a tutorial like https://medium.com/@bkwebster/how-to-get-instagram-api-access-token-and-fix-your-broken-feed-c8ad470e3f02 *might* work